# Alternatives to Expression Blend

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, expression-blend, .net-4.5

The transition from *Blend 4* to *Blend for Visual Studio* is scaring me.  I have installed the latest CTP for VS2012 Update 2 which includes WPF support for the built-in Blend (no longer using the Preview version).  However, some features are plainly broken:  Design-time resource resolution does not work anymore, and my project UserControls won't even load in the XAML designer.  I think I've narrowed the problem down to my using import projects to set the OutputPath of my projects to a common location.  Even so, the features and build feel very shaky and, what's worse, this all works in Blend 4!  However, I would like to use .NET 4.5 features, which Blend 4 doesn't support natively.

This is turning into a rock/hard-place situation for WPF developers.  I want 4.5, but I can't use the new version of Blend.  **Does anyone know of any good alternatives to *Blend for VS* for doing WPF design work in .NET 4.5?**

So far, my alternatives are to use the Visual Studio 2012 Designer directly, but there is no direct support for Behaviours, design-time data generation, the designer canvas isn't up to snuff (seriously, the mouse scroll doesn't zoom the canvas... how dumb is that?)  I could also try to mix and match, where my data processing is kept in one project, my control definitions in another, and have the controls target 4.0 so that I can use Blend 4.  That's painful, but it might work.  Finally, Microsoft has made it hard to flat-out buy Blend 4 if you don't already own it.  I'd be interested to hear of a third-party option, though, paid or free.

Comment: Voting to close as **too localized**. He's working with a pre-release CTP (not even a beta yet) and acting like it's the final replacement for a commercial product, so if anything this belongs as a specific report on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: This is a valid question:  .NET 4.5 exists as a released version of the framwork, and yet no public Blend product supports it directly.  I am asking for alternatives here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few, that I've played with

- [Kaxaml](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/kaxaml)
- [Resharper Xaml support](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/xaml_editor.html) (Requires Visual Studio)
- [XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (very basic compared to Blend)

I liked Kaxaml best amongst the three.

Comment: Kaxaml.com posted above leads to an indecent site, use this instead https://kaxaml.software.informer.com/

Comment: thanks @Smith - i found that there's a github repo to the software. Although I do not work on xaml anymore